# Faster function than datenum in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, date, performance

Does anybody knows a faster way to convert date string (2010-12-12 12:21:12.123) to number?

Comment: By number, do you mean a timestamp such as the often used "seconds since the Epoch"?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is often instructional to profile the built-in Matlab functions and extract just the internal functionality of interest.

In your particular case,

```
dtstr2dtnummx({'2010-12-12 12:21:12.123'},'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

is 3 times faster (takes 30% of the time) than:

```
datenum({'2010-12-12 12:21:12.123'},'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS')
```

where dtstr2dtnummx is an internal function (C:\Program Files\Matlab\R2011a\toolbox\matlab\timefun\private\dtstr2dtnummx.mexw32 on my Windows machine).

To gain access to this internal function, simply add its folder to the Matlab path using the `addpath` function, or copy the dtstr2dtnummx.mexw32 file to another folder that is already on your Matlab path.

Note that the string format is different between dtstr2dtnummx and datenum, so be careful!

To those interested, the folder above contains other interesting date conversion functions, so explore and enjoy!

Note 5/5/2011: I have now posted an article that expands this answer on http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/datenum-performance/

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot add private Matlab directories to the path, so for users who do not have the option of copying the file to their current directory, this solution won't work.

Comment: To clarify, users may not be able to add the file containing `dtstr2dtnummx` to their current directory because of copyright issues.

Comment: @Ricardo - I don't think there is any copyright issue here. I believe that you have a right to use any internal function when you purchase a Matlab license.

Comment: When I attended a training session a few months ago, the Mathworks personnel urged me not to do this when creating standalone Matlab applications. Hence my hesitation.

Comment: I would take their urging at the same level of seriousness as Apple's urging not to root the iPhone, or Ford's urging not to hand-customize their cars. You have a choice, and it is *your* decision whether or not to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Often you need to take a systems approach.  I had a very similar problem, when I was extracting thousands of dates from a DB.  It turns out that many modern DBs (Postgres, Sql server & Oracle are the ones that I tried) all can do the conversion from their date representations to the Matlab date representations several order of magnitudes quicker than the text to datenum on the matlab side.  If this data is coming from a DB, think DB-side conversion!!

Answer (score 2):

Presumably if you care about the time spent converting dates, you're converting **many** of them.  Even JIT optimizations in recent versions of matlab aside, you'll get much faster results calling

```
datenum(cellarrayofdates, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS');
```

than

```
for i=1:length(cellarrayofdates); datenum(cellarrayofdates{i}, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS'); end
```

If you're not already doing that, start there, since it allows matlab to reduce the overhead of figuring out your date format each for each call to the function.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this question is old. However, I managed to make a function that is approximately 30-40 times faster than datenum. Note: There are minor flaws depending on the usage. If anyone wants me to prefect it, just let me know.

Run on 1,792,379 rows:

- datenum - 11.463186 seconds
- datenumjck - 0.300503 seconds

Just read your file with textscan and interpret date and time as doubles and input along with date format to my function.

**Example:**

Assume data is formated as the following:

```
Data,2016-03-03,16:15:50;686,0.000000,-0.009500
Data,2016-03-03,16:15:50;696,0.000000,0.006500
Data,2016-03-03,16:15:50;706,0.000000,0.004500
Data,2016-03-03,16:15:50;716,0.000000,-0.006000
```

Read data:

```
fileID = fopen('myFile.csv','r');
formatSpec = '%*s %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %*[^\n]'; % Ignore first string, save
                                                 % date and time as doubles
                                                 % ignore all other data
data = textscan(fileID,formatSpec,'delimiter',',\t/:;-.\\ ');
fclose(fileID);
```

Specify date format and use datenumjck():

```
dateFormat = 'yyyy-mm-dd,HH:MM:SS;FFF';
numDate = datenumjck(data,dateFormat);
```

**Code:**

```
function num = datenumjck(data, dateFormat)

n = size(data{1});
dateFormat = textscan(dateFormat,'%s','delimiter',',/:;-.\\');
dateFormat = dateFormat{1};

k = find(strcmp('yyyy', dateFormat),1);
if ~isempty(k)
    y = data{k};
elseif ~isempty(find(strcmp('yy', dateFormat),1))
    y = data{find(strcmp('yy', dateFormat),1)};
else
    y = zeros(n);
end

k = find(strcmp('mm', dateFormat),1);
if ~isempty(k)
    m = data{k};
elseif ~isempty(find(strcmp('mmm', dateFormat),1))
    month = cellfun(@strfind,...
        repmat({'janfebmaraprmayjunjulaugsepoctnovdec'},...
        size(data),lower(data(find(strcmp('mmm', dateFormat),1)))));
    m = (month+2)/3;
else
    m = zeros(n);
end

k = find(strcmp('dd', dateFormat),1);
if ~isempty(k)
    d = data{k};
else
    d = zeros(n);
end

k = find(strcmp('HH', dateFormat),1);
if ~isempty(k)
    H = data{k};
else
    H = zeros(n);
end

k = find(strcmp('MM', dateFormat),1);
if ~isempty(k)
    M = data{k};
else
    M = zeros(n);
end


k = find(strcmp('SS', dateFormat),1);
if ~isempty(k)
    S = data{k};
else
    S = zeros(n);
end

k = find(strcmp('FFF', dateFormat),1);
if ~isempty(k)
    F = data{k};
else
    F = zeros(n);
end

ms = [0,31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334];

num = zeros(n);
for k = 1:n
    num(k) = y(k)*365 + ms(m(k)) + d(k) + floor(y(k)/4)...
        - floor(y(k)/100) + floor(y(k)/400) + (mod(y(k),4)~=0)...
        - (mod(y(k),100)~=0) + (mod(y(k),400)~=0)...
        + (H(k)*3600 + M(k)*60 + S(k) + F(k)/1000)/86400 + 1;
end
```